# A word that means "without sinister motivation" in an altruistic sense of sorts

Tags: single-word-requests

Heard someone say or read somewhere something along the lines of "to live in the altruistic and (?) service of others", where (?) was some word similar to "unmotivated" but in that it implied that there was no ulterior motive in the person's actions, that is, the action was not motivated by temporal or self-serving interests.

(?) = (not motivated by ulterior motives)

Is there a word for this, or am I just crazy?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that it might have been **unselfish**? Another word very similar in spirit to **unselfish** would be **selfless**.

Comment: But I feel as though "unselfish" is too similar in meaning to altruistic, and think that the word in question directly implied a lack of ulterior motive. That is, if this word exists and I'm not confabulating this memory

Comment: YES i think it was selfless. godbless thank you !!